# Microsoft Security Essentials & MsMpEng.exe hogging resources

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, ms-security-essentials

I've been using MSE for a couple months now, never had a single problem.  All of a sudden the process "MsMpEng.exe" will randomly go crazy and hog all my system resources so I can't do anything unless I kill it in the task manager. (I've quit the program for now and my comp is running smooth).  When I restart the program, reboot, whatever, it goes off and hogs all the resources again after a couple minutes.  If I kill the process it will go away and then come back a couple minutes later and do the same thing.  I've scanned with MSE, another antivirus and malware with no probs.  Any ideas?  Should I uninstall and find something else?  The thing is I've liked it so far.  I'm running Win7 64-bit.

Also, I'm not running any other conflicting security programs. This is the only one on my PC right now. Windows Defender is also off.

Comment: What resources are you talking about? CPU/Memory/IO/...?

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the amount of resources MSE uses. The following settings can decrease the resources usage without greatly effecting the effectiveness of MSE.

- look at the settings tab>"scheduled scan" settings in MSE you should see
  the option to limit the cpu usage
  from 10-100%.
- look at the "real time protection" settings and see what effect
  unchecking "enable network inspection
  system" and "enable behavior
  monitoring"
- look in the "advanced" settings and see if "scan archive files" or "scan
  removable drives" are enabled.
- verify your install is fully updated

Comment: +1 Didn't know that MSE allows you to limit CPU usage, nice!

Comment: Pretty sure the culprit was the behavior monitoring option. As soon as I disabled it and saved settings, CPU usage dropped considerably.

Comment: now, you need to do this through the group policy editor, which must be enabled first. you run `gpedit` then edit `System Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Defender Antivirus\Scan\Specify the maximum percentage of CPU utilization during a scan`, down to 5%. see https://www.itechtics.com/msmpeng-100-usage-cpu-disk/

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution,  but you can attempt to set the process affinity to a single processor core so it can't take all the resources.   This should leave your other processor core to do the other tasks you need.

This only works if you have a Multi-Core CPU obviously. :)

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-set-processor-affinity-to-an-application-in-windows/

Comment: This hogs a complete core, and will bother programs that use multiple cores. It might be more than just CPU.